# 13.04 Not working period

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, kernel

I have reinstalled this 4 times now and cant seem to get it to boot now.  I have a Phenom x6 AMD on a Gigabyte MB with 8 Gigs of ram and a Galaxy GeForce 210 GPU.  Everything I have read is pointing to the Nvidia and the current Kernel but cant find any work arounds to get it to even load to a working state.  I am also getting recursive fault errors, and have no clue what they are talking about.  I am almost to the point of dropping Ubuntu all together if they cannot fix this debacle unless someone has any thing that will help with this.  Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: (At the moment I am not allowed to make comments, so I'll post my comment at the Answer place) Have you ckecked the MD5 hash of your downloaded Ubuntu version? Here's a link where you can do it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes I hope it helps.

Comment: Does it look like this? http://i.imgur.com/EG6zyWQ.jpg (i have a Phenom II x4 965 and a nvidia gtx 550 ti)

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your shoes and I thought it was the graphics card, I would probably try taking it out and seeing if it will boot to see if that works or not. If it boots with the card out, you could try installing the drivers for the Nvidia cards from here: [Nvidia drivers](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/10/install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu.html).

If it does boot, you should check the logs and post them here so we could see what might be causing the problem.

From the Nvidia page:

> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
> ```

Comment: The xswat ppa does not have a raring repo, raring has the latest stable drivers currently